# delete row from gridview sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to be able to delete a row when I click on the delete button on that gridview. I have the aspx page and the code behind as well as the app code. The DeletePaymentCondition runs the store procedure to delete the row. But somehow the overall code doesnt work

aspx

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered " GridLines="None" 
        AllowSorting="True" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting">  
         <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderText="Payment Condition" HeaderStyle-CssClass="OGColor" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white" SortExpression="monthToQuarters">
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <span style="font-size:12px; color: #2980b9; text-align:left">
                      <asp:Label ID="lblUserId" runat="server" Visible="true" Text="<%# bind('payConditionId')%>"/>
</span>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="150"/>           
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

cs



protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblEmpID = (Label)gridPayment.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblUserId");  //This is Table Id load on Label1

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(lblEmpID.Text.ToString());


        dsPayment = objcommission.Delete(id);
        gridPayment.DataSource = dsPayment.Tables[0];
        gridPayment.DataBind();

    }
```

app code

```
public DataSet DeletePayment(int id)
{
    DataSet dsGetAllPayment;
    dsGetAllPaymentCondition = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(OGconnection, CommandType.Text, "Delete FROM tblPay where pay ='" + id + "'");
    return dsGetAllPayment;
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype of "payConditionId" field? and I thought `DeletePaymentCondition` is having a stored procedure, but it looks like an inline sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoul execute two different SQL, one for the delete and a new select one to retreive the new data.

The `DELETE` should be executed using in a `NonQuery` because it does not return rows (only the number of rows affected).

```
public DataSet DeletePaymentCondition(int ids)
{
    int rowsAffected = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(OGconnection, CommandType.Text, "Delete FROM [Accounting].[dbo].[tblPayConditions] where payConditionId ='" + ids + "'");
    DataSet dsGetAllPaymentCondition = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(OGconnection, CommandType.Text, "Select * FROM [Accounting].[dbo].[tblPayConditions]");
    return dsGetAllPaymentCondition;
}
```

As a good praxys, you should consider changing it into parametrized queries. In this case it is safe because of the integer conversion, but in similar code with string parameters you would be prone to SQL Injection attacks

Comment: Haven't done web forms in a very long time but you shouldn't have to rebind the data when clicking delete on the gridviewrow should you?  I thought it automatically removed the row and left the rest of the data there.

Comment: still doenst delete the row..Maybe there is something wrong with my .cs or .aspx code

Comment: set a breakpoint and check `rowsAffected` variable after the `ExecuteNonQuery` is being run, It should have a value greater than zero. Also check the value of `ids` before the `ExecuteNonQuery`. Is there a record with that ID in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I've made changes to the cs file and as well as the code provided by bradbury9.

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        int index = Convert.ToInt32(gridPaymentCondition.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        dsPaymentCondition = objcommission.DeletePaymentCondition(index);
        gridPaymentCondition.DataSource = dsPaymentCondition.Tables[0];

        updatePaymentConditionsWithoutRefresh();
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer helped you, I would suggest marking it as helpful

Comment: Also I had to put DataKeyNames="lblUserId" in the gridview for it to work. But thanks again!